# Android Pay - Full Wallet Confirmation Result Code 1 and Error Code 10

Tags: android, google-api, google-play, google-play-services, android-pay

For a while, Android Pay was working well. Until recently (end of May), I received the following error.

I'm referencing the publicly available Android Pay tutorial. During "Product Checkout" when a user confirms, I am seeing a **Request Code 1004 and Result Code 1** and it invokes the following:

```
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
  switch(requestCode) {
          case FullWalletConfirmationButtonFragment.REQUEST_CODE_RESOLVE_LOAD_FULL_WALLET:
                 Fragment fragment = getResultTargetFragment();
                 if (fragment != null) {
                     fragment.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
```

This invokes the FullWalletConfirmationFragment here:

```
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    int errorCode = -1;
    if (data != null) {
        errorCode = data.getIntExtra(WalletConstants.EXTRA_ERROR_CODE, -1);
    }

 switch (requestCode) {
     case REQUEST_CODE_RESOLVE_LOAD_FULL_WALLET:
            switch (resultCode) {
                 case Activity.RESULT_OK:
                    break;
                 case Activity.RESULT_CANCELED:
                    break;
                default:
                    handleError(errorCode);
                    break;
```

The resultCode has a value of 1, which is very strange to me. This references **Activity.RESULT_FIRST_USER** (1). What the heck is this? Anyway, this invokes handleError(), where the **Error Code is 10**!

I have no idea what Error Code 10 is. Looking at the **WalletConstants** class, Error Code 10 does NOT exist.

Any help would be appreciated. Here is my latest environment:

```
compileSdkVersion 23
buildToolsVersion '23.0.2'
defaultConfig {
    minSdkVersion 14
    targetSdkVersion 21

**gradle**
google-services:3.0.0
com.google.android.gms:play-services:+  // Appears to reference 9.0.0 which became available in May

**wallet environment**
 I've tried Sandbox Environment, Strict Sandbox Environment, and Test Environment.
```

Comment: Same error here, even with their demo app and my stripe key. Did you managed to get it working?

Answer (score 0):

Follow these steps to **Configure your app for production**:

1. Once you have completed the integration path, [download our Android

   Pay API checklist](https://storage.googleapis.com/support-kms-prod/0BF389FB583F92105484E7E3E2B2B875301D) and review your app against it
2. If you have enabled preauthorization, [generate a client ID for
   production](https://developers.google.com/android-pay/preauth#create_a_client_id) (unless you already have a client ID for an existing
   production app, published prior to your Android Pay integration).
   Note that the production client ID is mandatory, even if you
   previously set up a client ID for development.
3. Make sure that your APK is signed with the release key, not the
   debug key you used in the test environment. The debug key won't work
   in the production environment.
4. Set the WalletOptions environment parameter to
   WalletConstants.ENVIRONMENT_PRODUCTION.